# how to give new line in mailmessage.body section

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have sent mail using SMTP (ASP.NET).

I have written text in one line only, but I want to be in next line.

I used  `\n`, but it's not working.

Comment: what is the code behind that you are using

Comment: Constants.vbCrLf in C#.net and vbCrLf in VB.net returns a new line character.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

System.Environment.NewLine

If you format your email as HTML you can add a `<br />` to it.

To format as HTML use the IsBodyHtml property of the MailMessage class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way :

**Replace \n by \t\n**

The tab will not be shown, but the newline will work.

Comment: I do see the tab when viewing the email in Outlook. But this works better than anything else I've tried for a plain-text email.

Answer (score 0):

if IsBodyHtml == false, then https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82da38ac-ac20-4c9a-a2bd-8512d88fdd41/c-newline-in-email?forum=csharpgeneral suggests:

> Use %0D%0A to separate lines.
>
> To simplify, use “\r\n”, then call Uri.EscapeDataString for body and
>   subject before concatenation.

if IsBodyHtml == true, as suggested above, use `<br />`
You can use 
someText.Replace("\n", `"<br />"`) to replace newlines (any remaining \r from \r\n line endings will be ignored). Or use someText.Replace("\r\n", `"<br />"`).Replace("\n", `"<br />"`) to fix both line endings without any \r remainders, if line-endings are intermixed in text.